# Primitive roots

Tags: elementary-number-theory, primitive-roots

How would one go about in finding all of the primitive roots of a prime number?

I know how to check if for example a is a primitve root of the primitive number p.

We look at the expression $$ a^n \bmod p $$ for n = 1 to n = p -1. Once we go through all of the iterations we see if the remainders are unique and in the range of $$ (1, p-1) $$

How do I find for example all the primitive roots of 71, the method above seems highly time consuming...

Comment: You do not need to compute all powers if you know the factorization of $\varphi(p)$, see here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primitive_root_modulo_n#Finding_primitive_roots. Why do you want to have all primitive roots - and not only one, the smallest,  or the number of roots?

Comment: Finding one primitive root is a difficult problem - essentially brute force. Once you've found one generator, $g$, you can find all of them by taking $g^k$ where $k$ is relatively prime to $p-1$.

Comment: Because the questions on my Number theory tests are of the form find all the primitive roots of and then they give you a prime number...

Comment: Thanks for your input, essentially I could find the smallest one, and then just say the others will be that smallest one to the power of k where k is coprime with the given primtive number?

Comment: Yes essentially, but $k$ must be coprime to $p-1$ as @Matt B wrote in his answer and Thomas Andrews in his comment.

Comment: Oh, yes, of course $$ p - 1 $$, you do think that a solution like that would be full points on a test, I don't believe they want us to go brute forcing ? :)

Comment: I do not know. If you look at the wiki table, $71$ is kind of worst case: It has largest smallest primitive root $7$ and a large number of roots $24$. Systematically I would check $2,3\dots$ (you can exclude squares), then discover the smallest root $a=7$, then compute all powers $a^k$ with  $\gcd(70,k)=1$. If in doubt ask your teacher/lecturer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For $p$ prime, a primitive root always exists and there are in fact $\phi(\phi(p))=\phi(p-1)$ of them, where $\phi$ is the Euler totient function defined by $\phi(n)= |\{1\leq a \leq n | \gcd(a,n)=1\}|$.

So once you've found a primitive root $a$, all the others are of the form $a^m$ where $\gcd(m,p-1)=1$. Hence all you need to do is find a single primitive root.